# Segfault from Vector.end()?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I know that I'm doing something really stupid memory access-wise, but can't figure out how to fix it.

```
if(isKeyDown("DERP"))
{
    thisStack->pop();
}
```

calls

```
void aeonstack::pop()
{
    if(!aeonstack::statestack.empty())
    {
        if(aeonstack::statestack.size()>1)
        {
            aeonstack::statestack.at(aeonstack::statestack.size()-1)->cleanUp();
            aeonstack::statestack.pop_back();
        }
        else
        {
            aeon::log("WARNING: Tried to pop only state.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        aeon::log("WARNING: Tried to pop empty state stack.");
    }
}
```

which causes a segfault.

Full source code is available at [aeonsplice.com/segfault.zip](http://www.aeonsplice.com/segfault.zip)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RCB3A5EW

Comment: You should post a small, complete example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer variable thisStack doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere. Are you constructing the aeonstack for this pointer somewhere. I couldn't find it in the source files?

Comment: It seems I missed setting it in init(). Now I just have to figure out why the screen goes blank after popping a state. ^_^